# Deploying dotnet core projects in TFS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Does anyone know how to build a definition for a dotnet core project for IIS using using TFS 2017?

Problem I am having when I build and deploy currently it only produces a container type build which only includes 5 files and no dependencies.

Anyone help?

Comment: Which build and publish task are you using? Could you share your detail steps of your build definition？

Comment: I currently do the dotnenetcore tasks. Restore, built, test, coy to artifacts folder then publish the files to a location to store the builds. But I need to manually create a folder with the relevant files for IIS Inc web config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. I had to do a msbuild and publish using the msbuild task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dotnet command in [Command line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/command-line) task to restore the NuGet package and build/publish the output to a folder.

```
publish -c $(BuildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

After you've run the build, you could create a release definition to deploy your app to an IIS server.

More detail steps please refer below tutorial:

- [Build your ASP.NET Core app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core)
- [Deploy your Web Deploy package to IIS servers](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups)
- [Setting up .net core continuous integration build with VSTS/TFS](https://lazy-developer.xyz/blogs/dev/2017/4/setting-up-net-core-continuous-integration-build-with-vststfs)